# (SAS 9.4) Is any functions in SAS which can extract residual from regression equation?

Tags: function, sas

I need help to know a function can extract residual from regression equation.

I need that function to make 2-stage credit model. I want to extract a residual from first stage model(regression) and apply the residual to second stage model(y value).

It will be very helpful if there is proper function in SAS 9.4.

thank you

Comment: SAS doesn't work with functions for this type of analysis. The first SAS course of using SAS for statistical analysis is free on the SAS webpage and I highly recommend you look through it. Look up SAS Analytics U.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the documentation around PROC REG.

```
proc reg data=inData;
model y = x1 x2 x3;
output out=ouData r=resid;
run;
quit;
```

This takes data from the INDATA data set, regresses Y on X1, X2, and X3, and outputs the residuals in OUTDATA.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get fancy, you can do it 2-stage least squares with `proc model`.

```
proc model data=have;
    exo x1 x2 x3;
    endo y1 y2;

    y1 = b1 + b2*y2 + b3*x1 + b4*x2;
    y2 = b5 + b6*y1 + b7*x3;

    fit y1 y2 / 2sls;
    instruments _exog_;
run;
```